# Make a beautiful ROC curve with 4 models on it

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, roc, auc

I've trained 4 different xgboost ML models, I tested them and got the prediction scores with this line of code: (The fist column is the target feature so I exclude it when predicting):

```
predict(model, as.matrix(test_set[,-1]), type = 'prob')
```

so now, I have a data frame with the rows as the samples of the test set, and with 4 columns showing the prediction score for each samples in each model. Something that looks like this:

```
structure(list(rows = c("aa78a", 
"12200T", "1c2a5ac94492", "1d209304d988", "212T", "PBB", 
"35XDS16T", "1234H", "39T", "3ec4d3fc8bd1", "3f78044299b5", 
"4260a482", "30T", "43b757f5d8", "49c4c0e12POI"), model_meta= c(0.382992297410965, 
0.460950464010239, 0.447804838418961, 0.447804838418961, 0.460950464010239, 
0.447804838418961, 0.369836807250977, 0.447804838418961, 0.369836807250977, 
0.447804838418961, 0.382992297410965, 0.447804838418961, 0.369836807250977, 
0.447804838418961, 0.447804838418961), model_x2= c(0.460011065006256, 
0.52004611492157, 0.253930300474167, 0.222006008028984, 0.302200853824615, 
0.485153168439865, 0.20485857129097, 0.350892871618271, 0.331338971853256, 
0.295754462480545, 0.185829699039459, 0.618589639663696, 0.291316270828247, 
0.414723694324493, 0.210018843412399), model3= c(0.277256995439529, 
0.425392180681229, 0.182383552193642, 0.253527283668518, 0.329186052083969, 
0.305586904287338, 0.188975885510445, 0.238625407218933, 0.497761845588684, 
0.342641144990921, 0.156761467456818, 0.306724846363068, 0.152404963970184, 
0.428304076194763, 0.22887846827507), model4= c(0.565486133098602, 
0.564990341663361, 0.164183273911476, 0.15946152806282, 0.234778091311455, 
0.396436214447021, 0.172556579113007, 0.257463246583939, 0.43759897351265, 
0.200696632266045, 0.122483171522617, 0.586755096912384, 0.348238885402679, 
0.493290543556213, 0.252075374126434)), row.names = c("aa78a", 
"12200T", "1c2a5ac94492", "1d209304d988", "212T", "PBB", 
"35XDS16T", "1234H", "39T", "3ec4d3fc8bd1", "3f78044299b5", 
"4260a482", "30T", "43b757f5d8", "49c4c0e12POI"), class = "data.frame")
```

**All those predictions are binary. Meaning the target feature is binary in all models. In all models I used the same test set (same exact samples), it's just the features that were changed.**

I have two questions:

1- How do I know which side is which in the prediction score? For example, if it is 0.460950464010239, does that mean it is more probably class `0`? I guess I don't fully understand the meaning of the prediction scores.

2- How do I use those scores to plot all 4 models on the same ROC curve, with showing the name of each model and it's corresponding AUC score? Maybe via a nice legend on some corner of the plot?

I think something like this would look amazing:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the actual class column so the tpr and fpr can be calculated for different thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

1 - If the threshold is .5, then .46 would be classified as 0. One of the uses of an ROC curve is to find a more optimal threshold.

2 - You could do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rpart)
mod1 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, cp = .01)
mod2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, cp = .15)
mod3 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, cp = .2)
pred1 <- predict(mod1, type = "prob")[,2]
pred2 <- predict(mod2, type = "prob")[,2]
pred3 <- predict(mod3, type = "prob")[,2]

get_rates <- function(threshold, probs, actual, mod) {
  predicted <- factor(ifelse(probs < threshold, "absent", "present"))
  TP <- sum(actual == "present" & predicted == "present")
  FP <- sum(actual == "absent" & predicted == "present")
  TN <- sum(actual == "absent" & predicted == "absent")
  FN <- sum(actual == "present" & predicted == "absent")
  fpr <- FP/(TN + FP) 
  tpr <- TP/(TP + FN)
  data.frame(threshold = threshold, mod, fpr, tpr)
}

df1 <- map_df(seq(0, 1, .01), get_rates, probs = pred1,
 actual = kyphosis$Kyphosis, mod = "model 1")
df2 <- map_df(seq(0, 1, .01), get_rates, probs = pred2,
 actual = kyphosis$Kyphosis, mod = "model 2")
df3 <- map_df(seq(0, 1, .01), get_rates, probs = pred3,
 actual = kyphosis$Kyphosis, mod = "model 3")

df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3) 

ggplot(df, aes(fpr, tpr, color = mod)) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_x_continuous("false positive rate") + 
  scale_y_continuous("true positive rate") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I get NaN values for fpr and tpr

Comment: With this data or your data? If the latter you need to change my code to fit your situation.